# How to handle different optional callbacks in the same function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js

I have a function that works with different callbacks. Now I'm wondering if there is a better solution handling different callback functions.

My situation:

```
function prepare(type, callback){
    let obj = {}; //in real is this an external database

    for(let i=1; i<= 10; i++){
        obj['progress_'+i] = 0;
    }

    if(type === 'createNewUser'){
        callback(obj); //callback for function createNewUser(obj);
    }
    if(type === 'addToExistingUser'){
        callback(obj); //callback for function addToExistingUser(obj);
    }
}
```

My callback functions are:

```
createNewUser(obj){
    //create new user with obj;
}

addToExistingUser(obj){
    //add obj to existing user
}
```

2 ways to use prepare();

```
prepare('createNewUser', createNewUser);
prepare('addToExistingUser', addToExistingUser);
```

What is the best practice for this case? I would like to write good code.

Comment: Your example above does nothing special, no matter the condition it calls the same callback?

Comment: better you explain what you are trying to achieve, cuz you code snippet makes no sense.

Comment: when you know what callback method you are passing, why do you even need the type?

Comment: @AZ_ fair point. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Basically it's called bracket notation you create a map that has REFERENCE to the function, you can call that function with the desired params.

```
var callbacks = {

  createNewUser : createNewUserCallback,
  addToExistingUser: addToExistingUserCallback
}


function prepare(type){
    let obj = {};

    for(let i=1; i<= 10; i++){
        obj['progress_'+i] = 0;
    }

    callbacks[type](obj)
}

function addToExistingUserCallback(obj) {
     // Do stuff
}

function createNewUserCallback(obj) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

OR

```
var callbacks = {

  createNewUser : (obj) => { // function code goes here.} ,
  addToExistingUser: (obj) => {// function code goes here.} 
}


function prepare(type){
    let obj = {};

    for(let i=1; i<= 10; i++){
        obj['progress_'+i] = 0;
    }

    callbacks[type](obj)
}
```

To be fair option 1 is more readable.

Comment: Hmm (pulls a thinking face)

Comment: Ahh yeah I see what ya mean, I've found on SO that if you start using const/let etc sometimes it doesn't help the user because of the variance in supported JS versions - I was just literally saying to someone when do we as a community stop using the old syntax!

Comment: When you delete the comment I was replying to you make me look like I'm talking to myself, which I do enjoy, just not in public.

Comment: I've deleted my comments because you've replied something while I've commented, but your comments were loaded to me just after I've written mine...

Comment: Hehehe no worries buddy.

Comment: Sry @Mrk Fldig, with help of the comments I tryed to optimize my question/problem. Thanks. I will try your suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below example and add multiple callbacks in the same function according to your requirement -

```
function prepare(type, callback, secondcallback) {
    let obj = {};

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        obj['progress_' + i] = 0;
    }

    if (type === 'createNewUser') {
        callback(obj); //callback for function createNewUser(obj);
    }
    if (type === 'addToExistingUser') {
        secondcallback(obj); //callback for function addToExistingUser(obj);
    }
}


prepare('createNewUser', function (data) {
    console.log('First Callback data:', data);
}, function (data) {
    console.log('Second Callback data:' + data);
})


prepare('addToExistingUser', function (data) {
    console.log('First Callback data:', data);
}, function (data) {
    console.log('Second Callback data:' + data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If `type` is a string containing the name of the function to call, you can use `window[functionName]()`

```js
function foo()
{
    console.log("called foo");
}

function bar()
{
    console.log("called bar");
}

function baz(str)
{
  window[str]();
}

baz('foo');
baz('bar');
```

Or you can create your own object and store the functions in it :

```js
const FunctionObject = {}

FunctionObject.foo = function ()
{
    console.log("called foo");
};

FunctionObject.bar = function ()
{
    console.log("called bar");
};

function baz(str)
{
  FunctionObject[str]();
}

baz('foo');
baz('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if(type === 'createNewUser'){
    callback(obj); //callback for function createNewUser(obj);
}
if(type === 'addToExistingUser'){
    callback(obj); //callback for function addToExistingUser(obj);
}
```

With

```
fnc = window[callback];
if( fnc && typeof fnc === "function" ) {  //make sure it exists and it is a function
    fnc();  //execute it
}
```

Comment: Hey Ahmed - he's edited to say he's using NodeJS so "window" would only apply in the context of a browser! Welcome to StackOverflow though!

Comment: Thanks Mrk , i didn't see his comment about using it for Nodejs . You're right and thanks for wellcome again .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need `type` when you know what method to call or clarify if the `type` is not hardcoded, you simply can use prototypes as per your defined requirements.

```js
function Prepare(obj) {
 this.obj = obj;

}

Prepare.prototype = {
 createNewUser(obj = this.obj) {
  console.log('existing', obj);
 },
 
 addToExistingUser(obj = this.obj) {
  console.log('new', obj)
 }
}

let prep = new Prepare({a:1});
prep.createNewUser();
//or
prep.createNewUser({c: 3});

prep.addToExistingUser({b:2})
```

If the `type` is not hardcoded

```js
function Prepare(type, obj) {
 this.obj = obj;
 this.callback = this[type];
}

Prepare.prototype = {
 createNewUser(obj = this.obj) {
  console.log('existing', obj);
 },
 
 addToExistingUser(obj = this.obj) {
  console.log('new', obj)
 }
}

//if type is not hardcoded
let prep = new Prepare('createNewUser');
prep.callback({d: 4});
```